# Deadlock due to keylock involving 3 processes

Tags: sql, sql-server, concurrency, ssms, deadlock

I'm trying to determine how this deadlock occurred and what fix I need to do to prevent it from happening again.

I've attached deadlock graph image from SSMS, resolution provided by SSMS image is not good, I apologize.
[image]

What is going on here is 3 processes are locked in a cycle, all **waiting for the lock on the primary key for the table SecurityObject to be released**.

The primary key for this table is clustered and is a **composite key containing four columns**.

The statement that each process is running is shown below. It is a delete command, deleting all records from table that match on a single column. The column is a GUID identifier that is one of the four columns in the composite clustered primary key.

`DELETE FROM SecurityObject WHERE col1 = @val1`

Where col1 is one of the four columns in the primary key.

I'm struggling to understand is how this scenario could have happened? How can there be a deadlock scenario for a primary key lock?

Below is the deadlock xml graph:

```
<deadlock>
    <victim-list>
        <victimProcess id="processaeabf84108"/>
    </victim-list>
    <process-list>
        <process id="processaeabf84108" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 14:72057594041925632 (00f78314b62e)" waittime="1754" ownerId="6629325" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-08-04T15:16:55.747" XDES="0xaea526f498" lockMode="X" schedulerid="2" kpid="16620" status="suspended" spid="73" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-08-04T15:16:55.747" lastbatchcompleted="2017-08-04T15:16:55.747" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.747" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="RDXP0165C9JAWIE" hostpid="19084" loginname="REDMOND\RDXP0165C9JAWIE$" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="6629325" currentdb="14" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="SecurityAuthorization.DB.dbo.spDeleteAllSecurityObjects" line="5" stmtstart="342" stmtend="474" sqlhandle="0x03000e00b56a9938f8fcba00c3a7000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  DELETE FROM [SecurityObject] WHERE [EnvironmentId] = @EnvironmentI    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>  Proc [Database Id = 14 Object Id = 949578421]   </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="processaea64a9468" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 14:72057594041925632 (e0caa7da41f0)" waittime="3981" ownerId="6629329" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-08-04T15:16:55.750" XDES="0xaea9602408" lockMode="X" schedulerid="1" kpid="14152" status="suspended" spid="76" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-08-04T15:16:55.750" lastbatchcompleted="2017-08-04T15:16:55.750" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.750" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="RDXP0165C9JAWIE" hostpid="19084" loginname="REDMOND\RDXP0165C9JAWIE$" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="6629329" currentdb="14" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="SecurityAuthorization.DB.dbo.spDeleteAllSecurityObjects" line="5" stmtstart="342" stmtend="474" sqlhandle="0x03000e00b56a9938f8fcba00c3a7000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  DELETE FROM [SecurityObject] WHERE [EnvironmentId] = @EnvironmentI    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>  Proc [Database Id = 14 Object Id = 949578421]   </inputbuf>
        </process>
        <process id="processaea686fc28" taskpriority="0" logused="884" waitresource="KEY: 14:72057594041925632 (e0caa7da41f0)" waittime="2105" ownerId="6638253" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2017-08-04T15:16:57.627" XDES="0xaea9460e58" lockMode="X" schedulerid="2" kpid="6528" status="suspended" spid="79" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2017-08-04T15:16:57.627" lastbatchcompleted="2017-08-04T15:16:57.627" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.627" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="RDXP0165C9JAWIE" hostpid="19084" loginname="REDMOND\RDXP0165C9JAWIE$" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="6638253" currentdb="14" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
            <executionStack>
                <frame procname="SecurityAuthorization.DB.dbo.spDeleteAllSecurityObjects" line="5" stmtstart="342" stmtend="474" sqlhandle="0x03000e00b56a9938f8fcba00c3a7000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">  DELETE FROM [SecurityObject] WHERE [EnvironmentId] = @EnvironmentI    </frame>
            </executionStack>
            <inputbuf>  Proc [Database Id = 14 Object Id = 949578421]   </inputbuf>
        </process>
    </process-list>
    <resource-list>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594041925632" dbid="14" objectname="SecurityAuthorization.DB.dbo.SecurityObject" indexname="PK__Security__185B78FE57F79F91" id="lockaead1a0680" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594041925632">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="processaea686fc28" mode="X"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="processaeabf84108" mode="X" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594041925632" dbid="14" objectname="SecurityAuthorization.DB.dbo.SecurityObject" indexname="PK__Security__185B78FE57F79F91" id="lockae6d468f80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594041925632">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="processaeabf84108" mode="X"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="processaea64a9468" mode="X" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
        <keylock hobtid="72057594041925632" dbid="14" objectname="SecurityAuthorization.DB.dbo.SecurityObject" indexname="PK__Security__185B78FE57F79F91" id="lockae6d468f80" mode="X" associatedObjectId="72057594041925632">
            <owner-list>
                <owner id="processaea64a9468" mode="X" requestType="wait"/>
            </owner-list>
            <waiter-list>
                <waiter id="processaea686fc28" mode="X" requestType="wait"/>
            </waiter-list>
        </keylock>
    </resource-list>
</deadlock>
```

Here is execution plan of stored procedure:

[image]

Comment: Is col1 the first column of the composite PK?

Comment: Could you add also the XML content of deadlock graph event: right click on graph > Extract XML ... ?

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes, it is. How does that make a difference? The physical ordering of records on disk?

Comment: @JamesWierzba, if col1 weren't the leftmost key column, a scan would be required and greatly increase deadlock likelihood.

Answer (score 1):

After further testing, I've managed to isolate the root cause of deadlock scenario to be concurrent calls to both DeleteAll (delete subset of records in table) and Insert (inserts a record that matches the criteria of the DeleteAll).

The exact sequence of events that leads to the deadlock scenario remains unclear, but the issue is solved by **setting isolation level to `serializable`**.

It is an acceptable side effect that it will hurt performance (for my scenario, we do not care about this operations performance because these operations are not being waited on, it is a fire and forget process).

Comment: INSERT and DELETE statements are executed within same transaction (by different batches maybe) ?

Comment: They are separate in processes